# Google say URL is blocked by robots.txt but it isn't

Tags: search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, google-index, crawl-errors

My Google search console says that my submitted URL is blocked by robots.txt, but I checked header, tags and robots.txt it isn't. My URL was on #1 for my target keyword and daily get 1000 clicks before this error. After trying everything I have to duplicate page and make 301 redirect but issue not gone.
here's what error I am getting:
[image]
But When I Test Live URL it show everything fine:
[image]
here's my robots.txt

```
User-agent:*
Disallow:/search
Allow:/

Sitemap:https://www.chanakyadrishti.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap:https://www.chanakyadrishti.com/feeds/pages/default?orderby=UPDATED
```

Comment: Check your url using this tool: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I did and it say not blocked by robots.txt

Comment: What content-type is on that URL?   Is it an HTML page or something else like an image?   GSC doesn't report accurately for images and other content that Google doesn't index is web-search.  See [Google's URL inspection says my image URL is blocked by robots.txt — I don't even have one!](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125888/googles-url-inspection-says-my-image-url-is-blocked-by-robots-txt-i-dont-ev)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller it's a text/html page. I also duplicate it and 301 redirect it to new page but still getting  same error